# MATLAB parfor, error when indices contain constants

Tags: matlab, parfor

The following code shows this error

> Error: The variable out in a parfor cannot be classified.

```
N=5;
ini = 3;

l=ini:(N+ini-1);
out=cell(1,N);
parfor i=l
    out{i+(1-ini)} = func(i);
end
```

The problem occurs when a variable like `ini` is an index of any variable inside a parfor loop.
Can `ini` be introduced in such way that the code works without changing the structure?

MATLAB version R2017a.

Comment: Change of variables to `k`, where `k = i+1-ini` ?  Then `i = k+ini-1`

Comment: Thanks. That is a possible solution, but the real code is much longer and changing it may lead to a loss of readability that I would like to avoid, if possible. That was what I meant when I said without changing the structure.

Comment: If the first line of a loop body is `i = k+ini-1;` and all your calculations use `i`, with only storage to the cell array using `k`, how does that harm readability?

Comment: Yes, you are totally right. That solves the problem perfectly.